Torque on tendon driven inverted pendulum

I have this setup of an inverted pendulum and need help figuring out the force-torque relationship.
Let's start with the left pendulum, where I inserted all values I am interested in. The red arrow is supposed to be a tendon, to which I apply a force in the direction of the arrow, that results in a certain joint torque.
I am wondering what happens to the lever arm and torque if I mount the tendon to the other side? In this setup, the actuator is mounted at the bottom part of the pendulum, imagine it to be where the red F is. If I apply a force there (Imagine the tendon becoming shorter, like if a linear actuator was attached), what will be the joint torque and how can I visualize and caluclate it? The fact that the tendon wraps around the pendulum hinge confused me a lot. It is fine for my application to neglect the friction at the point where the tendon wraps around the hinge.
